# How can delete android ListView item please help So I've added a list item, and then I want to delete list item by position

Tags: parse-platform

How can delete android ListView item, please help.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBeJ8.jpg)

I'm parse.co to report that I am writing to transfer know but how do I delete text. So I've added a list item, and then I want to delete list item by position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Task task = mTasks.get(position);

task.deleteInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {

```
                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                 if (e == null) {

                                     task.deleteEventually();
                                     Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Kısa süre içinde silinecektir.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                     toast.show();

                                     } else {
                                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Silmede Hata Oluştu.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                    toast.show();
                                     }

                            }
                        });
```